# SQL join concat two different values

Tags: php, sql

I'm still in the process of learning SQL queries. I've tried searching around online, but I don't even know what terms I should be searching for, so I'm looking for someone to point me in the right direction. I have two tables -- appointments and logins. I'm trying to use the concat function to get the first and last name for both "apptFor" and "addedBy." Do I need to have separate queries? It seems like it should be able to get done in a single query.

```
<table border="1">
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td width="140" align="center"><strong>Appt Date/Time</strong></td>
       <td width="100" align="center"><strong>Appt For</strong></td>
       <td width="300" align="center"><strong>Appointment</strong></td>
       <td width="100" align="center"><strong>Added By</strong></td>
       <td width="100" align="center"><strong>Date Added</strong></td>
     </tr>
     <?php
            $query = "SELECT a.appID,a.appDate,a.appNote,a.apptFor,a.addedBy,a.added,concat(u.firstName,' ',u.lastName) as appAddedBy FROM appointments a ";
            $query .=" INNER JOIN logins u on a.addedBy=u.userid WHERE a.userID='$uid' order by appDate asc";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
        {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
    ?>
     <tr>
       <td><?php echo $row['appDate']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row['apptFor']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row['appNote']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row['appAddedBy']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row['added']; ?></td>
     </tr>
     <?php  }} ?>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You can `JOIN` the same table more than once by using different ***aliases***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need  tow name you should join two time the logins

```
     $query = "SELECT a.appID,a.appDate,a.appNote,a.apptFor,a.addedBy
            ,a.added,concat(u1.firstName,' ',u1.lastName) as appAddedBy  
              ,concat(u2.firstName,' ',u2.lastName) as appApptFor 
            FROM appointments a ";
        $query .=" INNER JOIN logins u1 on a.addedBy=u1.userid";
        $query .=" INNER JOIN logins u2 on a.apptFor=u2.userid 
                  WHERE a.userID='$uid' ";
        order by appDate asc";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

Comment: This solved it! I didn't realize I would need two separate joins (and therefore two separate aliases) for the same table. Thanks!

Comment: I tried yesterday and it was too soon, then I got sidetracked. It's been marked now. Thanks again!